# Microsoft Edge not displaying <iframe>

Tags: javascript, iframe, microsoft-edge

I have a button that creates a new tab and loads some simple HTML and an iframe with a data URI passed into it. The new tab opens and I can see that this is all displayed in the DOM using the navigation tools (F12). However the Iframe does not display in Edge browser. I receive the error`HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).`

Below image shows the DOM and that everything is loading as expected.

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: the server gave you a 404. is the url right?

Comment: why is this a bad question ? microsoft edge sucks and does not open websites that all browsers open.. such a big issue.. how can this quesiton be downvoted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be your issue: [MSDN data Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897.aspx).

> For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded resources. Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements.

Comment: Thanks, one of the comments in that page cleared it up for me ..

"IE9 removed the 32kb DATA URI limit.
The restriction that DATA URIs cannot be navigated to (e.g. cannot be used as the source of an IFRAME) remains in place."